# Javascript page load delay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My page has loading screen. The loading screen loads for 5 secs before fading out and displays rest of the divs in the body.

Now, the rest of divs in the body has its own animation. The problems is all the animations starts animating when the page loads. What i want is, the divs to start animation only after the loading screen finished its timeout which is 5s. I tried to add animation delay of plus 5s for each divs, but there are many divs and i dont think that is the best way.

this is the code i'm using for the loading screen timeout.

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
  $(".preloader").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Hook the animations on the other divs to the completion of the fadeOut on the preloader, like this:
$(window).on("load", function () {
  $(".preloader").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow", function () {
  // fire off animations on other divs
  });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery's `fadeOut`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#fadeOut-duration-easing-complete) allows you to specify a callback function after the animation is finished. This way, you need not add a delay for each one of the content you want to animate, but just specify the start of the animation inside the callback function of `fadeOut`.

Here's a working example. The text changes to red slowly after the initial `.preloader` fades out.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.preloader').fadeOut(1000, 'linear', () => {
    $('.content').css('color', 'red')
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.preloader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader"></div>
<div class="content">Some content</div>
```